# Anchor link not working in object tag

Tags: html, anchor, object-tag

new here and having a problem with the object tag.

I have a page embedded in the tag that is similar to a traditional FAQ page, in that I have a list of links at the top which are supposed to jump to the anchor tags for each section when clicked.

It works perfectly when the external page is loaded alone, but if the page is loaded in the object tag, nothing happens when the links are clicked.

I've tried everything from href="#name" to href="http://www.blah.com/blah.html#name" and it still won't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `iframe` instead of `object`. This lets you specify the target of a link to be the inline frame, using e.g. `<a href="..." target="qa">...</a>` with `<iframe name="qa" ...></iframe>`.